# How to display RequestID on enter/exit geofence?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-pendingintent, geofencing, android-geofence

I would like to display the RequestId (or name) of the geofence objects when enter/exit event happen. I can return the RequestID for the objects by calling mList.get(1).getRequestID(). But I see no way to pass this to the pending intent or to control individual enter/exit events for each geofence.

I would be really thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you getting this information from an IntentService or Broadcast receiver? If it's true, you should use the LocationClient to get the Fence IDs and the transition. Let me know if this is your question and I could help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "way to pass this to the pending intent"?

Comment: Where do you want to display the RequestID?